# Change length of quotes in variety plugin

Tags: 14.04, plugins

I have been using the variety plugin for ubuntu for last 1 year.

Usually I was able to get long quotes in the plugin. But I don't know what happened with the new version. The quotes get truncated at some specified length.

I tried searching for options in the plugin but could not find one.

If someone can help me figure out it would be of great help. I have attached an image below for reference. I want to increase the length by a little or adjust fonts so that somewhat longer quotes can also fit in.

[image]

Comment: What is this variety plugin? Googling brings up a wallpaper change: http://peterlevi.com/variety/how-to-install/

Comment: Yes, It's an awesome plugin, changes the overall look of Ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: This is how it looks for me.

[image]

I installed variety from https://launchpad.net/~peterlevi/+archive/ubuntu/ppa and using version 0.6.3-0~581~201611011900~ubuntu16.10.1 . Try updating to that version (or see if the problem is with quote itself)

---

Did you try a couple of things ? In Preferences -> Effects -> Quotes

- In Appearance, try decreasing text font
- In placement, try increasing Quotes Area width (and try changing horizontal/vertical positions also)

<del>(I tried but haven't yet got big quote to verify these settings)</del>

Comment: No. These solutions doesn't change the problem. It is still the same. I am using the tumblr plugin and quotes are fetched from tumblr

Comment: @JayChakra Your question fails to mention that (tumblr) detail.  That doesn't mean this answer is wrong, it just means you failed to [ask a good question](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a simple font issue. Change your default font for quotes.
You can do it via: **preferences**->**effects** tab->**quotes**->**appearance**->**text font**

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Comment: explained how to do it

Comment: It doesn't do the job.

Comment: @JayChakra please explain better...

Comment: I tried doing the suggestion which you have posted but the result is still the same.